# The connection property has not been set or is null

Tags: mysql, vb.net, exception, date, command

When I run this function

```
    For RepeatBooking = 1 To 51
        dateConvertedDateToBook = dateDateToBook.Date
        dateDateToBook = dateDateToBook.AddDays(7)
        strDateToBook = dateConvertedDateToBook.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

        Try
            Dim command As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
            Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO bookings SET Date=" & "'" & strDateToBook & "',RoomID='" & strComputerRoomToBook & "',Length='" & intNewBookingLength & "',Period='" & intNewStartPeriod & "',UserID='" & intid & "'"
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
            SQLConnection.Open()
            command.CommandText = sqlQuery
            command.Connection = SQLConnection
            reader = command.ExecuteReader
            SQLConnection.Close()
        Catch excep As Exception
            MsgBox(excep.ToString)
        End Try

    Next
```

in my program I get an error saying "The connection property has not been set or is null"
How can I get rid of this?

It goes to the exception when it gets to SQLconnection.Open() 
I created the ServerString and MySQL connection at the top of the module like so:

```
Dim ServerString As String = "Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=**********;Database=rooms"
Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the exception? Can you show your code where you declare and initialize `SQLConnection`?

Comment: Don't concatenate sql-strings but use parameters, don't use `string` for `date`, use `Using`-statement (or `Try-Catch-Finally`) to ensure that your connections gets closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening a connection without its property
It should be,

```
Dim SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(ServerString)
SQLConnection.Open
```

Also, you may want to use the `USING` function so that your connection is properly closed.
It seems you are just inserting a bunch of values to your database and not retrieving anything so why do you use a DataReader?
Your code should be something like this:

```vb
Using SQLConnection = New MySqlConnection(ServerString)  
    SQLConnection.Open  'You should open a connection only once
    For RepeatBooking = 1 To 51
        dateConvertedDateToBook = dateDateToBook.Date
        dateDateToBook = dateDateToBook.AddDays(7)
        strDateToBook = dateConvertedDateToBook.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        Try
            Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO bookings SET " & _ 
                "Date='" & strDateToBook & "'," & _
                "RoomID='" & strComputerRoomToBook & "', " & _
                "Length='" & intNewBookingLength & "', " & _
                "Period='" & intNewStartPeriod & "', " & _
                "UserID='" & intid & "'"
            Dim command = New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, SQLConnection)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery
        Catch excep As Exception
            MsgBox(excep.Message)
        End Try  
     Next  
End Using
```

Also, you may want to change how to pass your values into a parameter. This will prevent SQL Injection.